# Get views for subscribers only

Tags: youtube-api

Is there a possibility to calculate video views generated only by subscribers? In the Youtube Analytics user interface in Traffic Source section there is possible to grab this count, as in screenshot below:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is the `insightTrafficSourceDetail` dimension, which allows you to specify the SUBSCRIBER traffic source. You can further break down the numbers by traffic from subscriber emails, the "my subscriptions" feed that subscribers have on their homepage, views that originated from a "new uploads" feed that subscribers see, etc. The only thing you WON'T get from this dimension are the views from users who are subscribing to your channel but who navigate directly to your video (i.e. if a friend emailed a link or something); in other words, the tracking is really on the source of the click (aggregating all sources that indicate subscriber) rather than actually looking at a username and determining they've subscribed at some point.

However, having said that, I wouldn't be surprised if the interface you've indicated above uses the same numbers for calculating its report.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/dims#Traffic_Source_Dimensions